# Cakephp + Foundation (sass)

Tags: cakephp, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I have created a new CakePHP project and installed Zurb Foundation thanks to "composer".

I have two issues. First, I would like to know how to compile scss files from Foundation (located in the vendor folder) and include them into my view. For now, I have installed compass to compile some custom scss files and it works fine but I don't know how to include files from Foundation. Secondly, I would like to know how to add js file from Foundation into my view.

Thanks for your help

Snoopy

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is just download foundation and save it to your webroot folder. Perhaps by this you will have to manually update foundation, as composer will not see it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't want the easiest solution, I want the most elegant solution :) !! If composer install Foundation in the vendor folder I hope there is a solution to work with it.